# time series data in a relational database?

Tags: database, optimization, database-design, time-series, data-warehouse

I have time series data in a relational database (postgres). Data  import to the database every 5 minutes, but imput get overwritten during the day, meaning at the end of the day there is only 1 record for that day for specific id (id and date->  composite PKs).

current process  is like this ->Data comes in and is evaluated the same way 1:1.  (data comes in every table as they are in source, there is many redundancy.

3 problems:

- currently performance of getting data out of database(reading) is fast (good performance)

frontend get query from this database and show data. result of the query is very fast. if I do normalization then getting the query become slower, but writing and updating become easier.
how can I optimize this database?

- missing data (*ignore this problem* )

if we are able to store more records daily (history of one ID in different points of time everyday) then we can show comparison of two points in time in a day. does database support huge amoount of data every day?

- DWH

source is just one, all data come from one source. can we have DWH for it or since source is only one, there is no need for it?

Edit:

How can I optimise this database?

currently there is only one Schema in a database. Data comes in and is evaluated the same way 1:1. writng is hard since we have redundany.

my solution:

I want to create 3 schemas for this database.

1 schema, for inserting data into tables, tables structure is base on data source. ( I assume data remains here temporary, and will be transfer in second schema)

2 schema, incoming data stored, and  data is  structured in 3NF.

3 Schema, denormlising data again because we need to get fast query (fast reading is required).

Comment: What's problem are you trying to solve? Performance? Missing Data? Two other reasons for a datawarehouse are 1. To load data into a data model that supports reporting; 2. Run queries against the datawarehouse instead of the source to stop load ocurring against the source (operational) system.

Comment: Thank you for the response. 
there are two problem (missing data and good performance),my boss, wants all things together. if we are able to store more records daily then we can show comparison of two points in time in a day.

in general, base on your expanation having DWH  for their purpose is useful because they won't use source at the same time for inputing data and getting query.
(good performance is important , front end need fast reading)
so having DWH making the performence faster? right?

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. Please use standard spelling & punctuation. [ask] [Help]

Comment: Yes a DWH allows you to optimise the entire database for analysis (reads). I can't help you with missing data, that's a data engineering question and there are no details in your question on how this is currently implemented

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your three schema model is exactly how this has been done for many years.

**Schema 1:**

Names: Staging/Landing/Ingestion

Schema matches the source system but it is cleared and reloaded for every load batch. Typically has a "looser" schema definition to allow for import and capture of bad data

**Schema 2:**

Names: Replica/ODS/Persisted data store

Schema 2 is never cleared, it's permanent. Following a data load, this layer should look exactly like your source systems. Data in schema 1 is "merged" into schema 2 each time. For example on a daily load cycle, Schema 1 just contains that days data but schema 2 contains the entire history of data loaded. Reference data is merged on a known primary key. Transactional data might be merged on a key or it might be merged on a "windowing" basis - i.e. delete the last days data from schema 2 and load schema 1 in

Some people like to have a "point in time view" where they can recreate what the source system looks like a historical point in time. I've never seen anyone use that though.

**Schema 3:**

Names: Business Layer/Star Schema/Reporting Layer/Datamart/Sematic Layer

Layer 2, which is usually a replica of an OLTP data model (OLTP is optimised for entering data). This is transformed into a data model that is optimised for reporting.

The tried and tested data model here is a star schema. It's been around for decades. If you research any reporting tool (i.e. Power BI), thay all say that the preferred data model to report from is a star schema. Yes a star schema is denormalised and has other benefits beyonf perforamnce, for example it is more easily understood by a business user, supports slowly changing dimensions etc.

All these concepts are explained further online but of you have any specific questions happy to expand further

Comment: currently with one schema we are able to read data in every 5 minutes forour frontend software , (however we also write every 5 minuets in the same schema and read from exactly the same schema) if I create 3 schemas, is it still possible to read every 5 min? because in 3 schema we need time transfer data from staging area to core and then Business Layer